# What's an appropriate regex to split this line using scala?

Tags: regex, scala, csv

I'm trying to split this line coming from a CSV file, to obtain the different matching groups from this (sample) line (file has around 750k lines):

919191911919,"La dama de hierro descubrió la ternura".(via@annabosch) Margaret Thatcher (86 años); ayer en el parque: http://host.com/gm2EEXqn ,P,AGREEMENT

As you can see there are four main parts in the line, id,free text, sentiment, option. Also, many characters in the content part (La dama de hierro...) and I don't know how to build a correct regex to obtain it like this: (id, txt, sent, opt).

What I've tried so far:

```
val fullRegex = """(\d+),(.+?),(N|P|NEU|NONE)(,\W+|;\W+)re?""".r
```

Works for some lines but fail for others.

Comment: The easiest way is `.splitBy(",")`, but it won't work if you have nested commas. I recommend that you using something like this: https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv

Comment: As a mater of fact @nmat, the content is free text, I cannot expect it to not contain commas or any other characters. I'll check out the link you provided.

Comment: "different matching groups" - can you please show the result you expect?

Comment: @radumanolescu it is right there in the question... given the sample string, I'd like to obtain Some(id, text, sent, opt).

Comment: Any samples of failed to match this regexp strings?

Comment: How can anyone provide a regex that matches all kinds of lines, if you do not provide them? You should show a representative selection of lines and ask for a regex that works on all of the shown ones.

Comment: @rumoku the line in the example fails, but this line: 456544889786728451,hola la vida es buena!,P,AGREEMENT works perfectly.

Comment: @ziggystar I cannot provide 750k lines here, I think it is enough to say that the content part is free text and it can contain any characters, not only letters or numbers. If that were the case, I wouldn't be asking this question, it's way too easy to accomplish the split.

Comment: can't believe it: both lines fails for me. I've remove re at the end and lowercased both W+ and it works properly for me. test it here: rubular.com

Comment: Well, that's weird, I tried removing those as well, but completely fails with the line in the question.

Comment: if the number of fields is fixed and things like 'P' or 'AGREEMENT' are part of a list of fixed keywords, doing this programatically (or even using ANTLR) may actually be easier and more robust than a Regex

Comment: @BrunoGrieder thanks for your suggestion, I'm getting started in this and haven't heard about what you're suggesting until now. Yes, AGREEMENT and P are fixed keywords.

Comment: Assuming the number of fields is fixed i.e. 4 and you can guarantee there is no comma in fields 1, 3, 4 simply scan forward to the first comma to get the first field, then backward from the end to the first 2 commas to get the last two fields. The second field is what lies in between

Comment: @BrunoGrieder that might be a valid approach, but I just wanted to find a way to do it using regex. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JorgeCespedes :) not everything is better solved with Regex or jQuery

Comment: If you are reading a CSV file, then commas should be properly escaped as well as double quotes. There is a standard for escaping charaters and delimiter and there are libraries that implement this standard. You should use them instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: After reading all the comments, I think `val fullRegex = """(.*?),(.*),(.*),(.*)""".r` should work.

Comment: @nmat agreed but my experience is that there are a lot of badly formatted CSVs out there and when you are on the receiving end, you cannot not always request for a change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is powerful but sometimes it's hard to get right and cover all possible input formats. In this case it might not be needed.

```
val in = """919191911919,"La dama de hierro descubrió la ternura".(via@annabosch) Margaret Thatcher (86 años); ayer en el parque: http://host.com/gm2EEXqn ,P,AGREEMENT"""
val inSplit = in.split(",")

val id   = inSplit.head                          // String = 919191911919
val txt  = inSplit.tail.init.init.mkString(",")  // free form text
val sent = inSplit.init.last                     // String = P
val opt  = inSplit.last                          // String = AGREEMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

As Bruno Grieder pointed out in the comments to the question, this can be handled more robustly [without using regular expressions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).

If this is not a well formatted CSV file (meaning, fields containing commas enclosed in quotation marks, quotation marks in field values escaped etc), an alternative is to realize that the first field does give you the ID and the last two fields do give you the sentiment and the option. Everything else is free text, so the structure of a line is rather simple.

Of course, if the file is indeed well-formatted CSV, use a library built for that purpose.

Assuming this is not well-formatted CSV, first split by a comma, put the first and the last two fields in their respective variables, and join the rest of the fields using a comma to recover the text.

I don't know much Scala, so the code is rather primitive. Improvements welcome:

```
val line = """919191911919,"La dama de hierro descubrió la ternura".(via@annabosch) Margaret Thatcher (86 años); ayer en el parque: http://host.com/gm2EEXqn ,P,AGREEMENT"""

val id :: rest = line.split(",").toList
val text = rest.slice(0, rest.size - 2).mkString(",")
val sentiment = rest(rest.size - 2);
val option = rest.last;

for (x <- List(id, text, sentiment, option))
  println(x)
```

Output:

```
$ scala test.scala
919191911919
"La dama de hierro descubrió la ternura".(via@annabosch) Margaret Thatcher (86 años); ayer en el parque: http://host.com/gm2EEXqn
P
AGREEMENT
```

This will also work with embedded commas in the text (although there is some extra work involved in splitting and recombining the text field). For example, if `line` is:

```
val line = "1,this is some text with one, two, three, and four commas (,),7,8
```

This is the output you'll get:

```
1
this is some text with one, two, three, and four commas (,)
7
8
```

Comment: Yes. That was my proposal. Regex is not a magic wand that is best suited for everything and anything

Comment: @nmat Yes it will, see example.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder I see your original comment under the post, I missed that originally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the text is enclosed in double quotes, you can first replace all commas inside the double quotes, then split at the commas, then put the commas back. The drawback of this solution is that you need to use a Unicode char that is guaranteed to not be present in your file

```
object CSVFixer {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    split(line) foreach println
  }

  val line = """919191911919,"La dama de hierro descubrió la ternura".(via@annabosch) Margaret Thatcher (86 años); ayer en el parque: http://host.com/gm2EEXqn ,P,AGREEMENT"""

  private val AltSep = '\u0080' // Unicode char that we reasonably expect to not have in the input
  val fieldSeparator = ","

  private[this] def unSep(s: String) = {
    val SepChr = fieldSeparator.charAt(0)
    var inQS = false
    for (c <- s) yield {
      c match {
        case '"' =>
          inQS = !inQS; c
        case SepChr if inQS =>
          AltSep
        case _ => c
      }
    }
  }

  def split(line: String) =
    unSep(line).split(fieldSeparator, -1) // do not discard trailing empty strings
      .map(_.replace(AltSep, fieldSeparator.charAt(0)))
      .map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))

}
```